# How to build a jar file with maven/spring boot without building the .jar.original file?

Tags: java, maven

I have looked all over for an answer to this question, but was not able to find one. I want to build a spring boot project with the maven command "mvn install", the command produces 2 jar files. One titled application.jar and the other titled application.jar.original. Is there a pom setting, or something that will allow one to build only the .jar file and not build the .jar.original file?

Comment: Out of the curiosity - why would you like not to? I am asking because there might be another solution to your problem

Comment: I want to do this because I am using AWS code pipeline to deploy a spring boot application to an elastic beanstalk server. The Elastic beanstalk documentation explains that if your deployment includes more than 1 jar file then you have to include a Procfile which determines the processes that will run each jar. I do not want to do this because I have no need for the .jar.original file. I would prefer to just not build it. My elastic beanstalk instance is throwing an error at the moment because there are 2 jars and no procfile

Comment: If you deploy to an beanstalk server you should only deploy the correct file...I would say take a look here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-artifact